# Ros2 in windows10 (failed to create process) error

Tags: windows-10, ros2

C:\Windows\system32>call C:\dev\ros2-windows\local_setup.bat
"[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."

C:\Windows\system32>ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker

failed to create process.

C:\Windows\system32>

I installed all the packages according to ros2 documentation...But i faces this error...

I tried providing the python path to the environment variables setup..

Comment: Please ask ROS 2 related questions on https://robotics.stackexchange.com from now on